# How to get the true textual verbose "No GUI boot + OS boot information" working again in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, logging

I find myself frequently needing much more information at Windows 10 startup than what we can seem to coax out of it now. It used to be possible to go into `msconfig` and select some options to get the desired result:

[image: really verbose boot]

Everything I've tried simply doesn't ever give me the `ntbtlog.txt` on screen like you get with Safe Mode (following excerpt from `ntbtlog.txt`):

```
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Version 10.0 (Build 19041)
 7 29 2021 19:37:32.500
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\hal.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\kd.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\mcupdate_GenuineIntel.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\CLFS.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tm.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\PSHED.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\BOOTVID.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\FLTMGR.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\msrpc.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\ksecdd.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\clipsp.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\cmimcext.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\werkernel.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\ntosext.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\CI.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\cng.sys
...
```

What can be done to bring this back?

Comment: I suggest the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1140309/windows-10-log-info-when-starting

Comment: It would be nice if that worked @noraj, but it does not.